# Is there a way to determine capacity of ResourcePool in AnyLogic at runtime?

Tags: optimization, anylogic

I am working on an optimization model using AnyLogic. The decision variables include number of agents to be placed at two locations based on some data. Objective is to maximize utilization of agents. I have created these agents using Resource Pool functionality of Process Modelling Library where I specify Capacity using a parameter "numAgents". However, doing so, places equal number of agents on both locations. Is there a way AnyLogic can determine the optimal number of agents at each location as an output while at the same time making use of the Resource Pool functionality?

Thanks.

Comment: use different parameters for each resourcePool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Felipe suggests: use 1 parameter to define each resource pool capacity. Then, create an optimization experiment and let it vary those 2 parameters.

(optimization experiments work with as many parameters as you like)

Comment: Thanks. As the model grows in size (instead of 2 locations and 2 resource pools, I have ~40), is there a way in AnyLogic to specify an array of decision variables? Or will I have to specify 40 resource pools and 40 parameters explicitly?

Comment: You can always create an agent that has 1 pool and 1 location, then initialize that agent 40 times or more.